# How to add specific bin width in python code

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I am new in python so bear with me.

I wrote a code to generate random numbers in python, then plotted it but did not know how to put the bin width in the code! my bin width should be 0.1

This is my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

import random

data = [random.randint(1,100) for _ in range(10000)]

plt.hist(data)

plt.show()
```

Comment: 0.1 what? You might want to look at the `rwidth` argument of [`plt.hist()`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html)

Comment: @sacul 0.1 data units is the standard meaning.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to directly set the bin width of a histogram plot. But this is not a big problem since you can compute the bins to match the desired bin width.

You may e.g. create an array between the minimum and maximum value of your data and a step size of `0.1`. This array can be used as bins for the histogram.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

data = np.random.randn(10000)*10

bins = np.arange(data.min(), data.max()+.1, 0.1)

plt.hist(data, bins=bins)

plt.show()
```