# Change Histogram Tick Size

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, histogram

I am plotting a dataframe of ratio values where the values lie between -0.2 and 0.4. To plot the histogram I am simply using

```
sheet = pd.read_csv('Spread_Ratio.csv') #read excel sheet containing values
df = sheet['Ratio'] #where the 'Ratio' col is just values between -0.2 and 0.4
df.hist()
plt.show()
```

which returns the following histogram.

[image: Histogram]

- Here my x axis is incrementing in ticks of 0.1, but I would like to see the data using 0.01 tick size across the xaxis. What do I need to alter in order to switch this?

Comment: Share your code which plots this figure. It's easier to help then

Comment: The dataframe has some empty bins, try: `df.hist(bins=20)` see https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html?highlight=matplotlib%20pyplot%20hist

Comment: There is no direct way to specify the bin width, but you can specify which bins to use as e.g. shown [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50396015/how-to-add-specific-bin-width-in-python-code/50398085#50398085).

Answer (score 0):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

sheet = pd.read_csv('Spread_Ratio.csv') #read excel sheet containing values
df = sheet['Ratio'] #where the 'Ratio' col is just values between -0.2 and 0.4

fig, axes = plt.subplots()

df.hist(ax=axes)

axes.tick_params(labelsize='x-large')

plt.show()
```